# Save and show input value in session storage

Tags: javascript, html, storage

I have input number and button with text on subpage.

```
<input id="quantity" type="number">
```

I want to save value from input and show on button.

```
<a id="button2" data-role="button">You have "value" coins</a>
```

How i can do it?

Comment: Have you tried something? It would be useful if you provide some snippet with your JS code.

Comment: Some basic research on the web would get you the fundamental components needed to write some starting code to attempt this. This is not a tutorial site, you are expected to show attempts to solve your issue yourself then when you have real code that doesn't work as expected people will help

Comment: $(function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('quantity');
});

Comment: var data = sessionStorage.getItem('button2');

Comment: You can edit your original post and add the snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well,

Here is solution

```
document.getElementById('quantity').onkeyup = function() {
    var quantity=this.value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('quantity',quantity);
    document.getElementById('button2').innerHTML='You have '+ sessionStorage.getItem('quantity')+' coins';
};
```

Here is jquery version:

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function(){
    var quantity=$(this).val();
    sessionStorage.setItem('quantity',quantity);
    $('a').text('You have ' +  sessionStorage.getItem('quantity') +'  coins');
});
```

Comment: Question isn't tagged jQuery. If using a dependency not tagged you should be mentioning it